# Number seq is getting increased if I just open and close a form without saving it

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

While using the methods in form, the number seq is getting created but if I just open a form and close it without saving, The number seq is getting increased. Can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement all the calls to the number sequence framework as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/number-sequence-framework#aa608474collapse_allen-usax60gif-forms).

Also you have to mark the number sequence as "Continuous" if you want to reuse unused numbers.

Method in form:

```
public NumberSeqFormHandler numberSeqFormHandler()
{
    if (!numberSeqFormHandler)
    {
        numberSeqFormHandler = NumberSeqFormHandler::newForm(
            FCMParameters::numRefWorkOrderNum().NumberSequenceId,
             element,
             FCMWorkOrders_DS,
             fieldnum(FCMWorkOrders, WorkOrderNum)); 
    }
    return numberSeqFormHandler;
}
```

Methods in form datasource:

```
public void create(boolean _append = false)
{
    element.numberSeqFormHandler().formMethodDataSourceCreatePre();
    super(_append);
    element.numberSeqFormHandler().formMethodDataSourceCreate();
}

public void delete()
{
    element.numberSeqFormHandler().formMethodDataSourceDelete();
    super();
}

public void write()
{
    super();
    element.numberSeqFormHandler().formMethodDataSourceWrite();
}
```